# Convert MS Access 97 TO MySQL 5.5 (Is there any Tools ?)

Tags: ms-access-97

I have huge industry level database in MS Access 97, I am redesigning the application and want to migrate all my existing data to MySQL 5.5.
Is there any tool available so that I can migrate all my existing data (MS Access 97) along-with schema to MySQL 5.5 without loosing any previous data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a freeware product that I've been using for about a year and it works great for converting msaccess 97 database to MySQL

It's called - Bullzip MS Access to MySQL